# Order of catch clauses

Tags: c#, exception

When using a framework method, the description you get when you highlight over it will list the exception(s) possibly raised.

Does it matter if you write the catch handlers in this order? E.g. SqlConnection.Open() can throw:

System.InvalidOperationException
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException

It is listed in that order. Should my catch handlers follow this order? If so, why?

Also, some methods such as SqlDataAdapter.Fill() return an int but no error is reported by Visual Studio if I don't have a variable to store the return value. Why?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should place your catch handlers not in the order they are listed in the documentation, but in the order of priority for your particular circumstances.

In saying that, if you are accessing a SQL Server database and get a SQL exception then it is unlikely your application will be able to continue, so the `SqlException` should probably be high priority.

**Update**: I omitted the part about the order of Exception inheritance (from most derived to base), as I incorrectly assumed this was a given. Other posters mentioned this explicitly.

Comment: If you have enough catch blocks on a single try that you need to list them in priority order in order to understand it, I would assume your code needs refactoring. :-P

Answer (score 10):

The order is irrelevant unless one of the exceptions named in a catch handler inherits from another exception named in another handler, in which case the more-derived catch should come first (or it will never be called).

The runtime will go through the catch blocks in the order they are listed, executing **only** the first one that matches, so if you have the following, only the first catch block will be executed, even if an ArgumentException is thrown:

```
try
{
  throw new ArgumentException("foo");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
catch (ArgumentException aex)
{
  // Will never be executed.
}
```

Answer (score 5):

(I agree with Mitch, catch in order of priority for your circumstances as it makes the code more maintainable.)

I also want to add that you **must** catch in order of inheritance from lowest subclass to highest parent class.

for example, If you want to catch System.Exceptions and System.InvalidOperationExceptions, you **must** catch the InvalidOperationException first, because it is a subclass of System.Exception. If you have the catch for System.Exception first that would take precedence and your catch block for InvalidOperationException would never get triggered.

Comment: This I already know. Exception is the most generic type (all exceptions inherit from it), so along the chain, a handler above will likely (But maybe not always) catch the exception. What I am wondering is, the two exceptions in my opening post of this thread are disparate/not related, so I guess in that case I order them in priority or perhaps likelihood?

Answer (score 1):

The Order of the `catch` doesn't matters, but it should be noted that the base exception should be written at the end, after all the derived exception.

Also you can order catch blocks according to the priority or occurence of most likely errors in the application

If we write in a wrong way

```
catch (Exception ex) {
    strMessage = ex.Message.ToString();
} catch (ArgumentNullException aex) {
    strMessage = aex.Message;
}
```

The compiler will report error in the above case and the error will be this  - A previous catch clause already catches all exceptions of this or of a super type `System.Exception`.